# How to generate random string with required length in Vim?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, gvim, original-vim, text-generation

I am using this code for console log

```
nmap cll yiwocll<Esc>p
```

I wanted to add some random string inside this console log, assume 10 characters symbols length.

How to achieve this?

Comment: `r!base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 10`

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? If the solution fit your need could you accept it using the v buttonnext to the arrow voting button. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
function! RandomString(n)
  let ret = ""
  for i in range(a:n)
    let j = rand()
    let c = nr2char(char2nr('a') + (j % 26))
    let ret .= c
  endfor
  return ret
endfunction

echo RandomString(10)
```